# Error in : "This would encourage us to come up with more such content as these."

Tags: grammar

> If you like our content and appreciate our efforts please press the G+
>   button and recommend us. This would encourage us to come up with more
>   such content as these.

"This would encourage us to come up with more such content as these."

Is there any grammatical mistake in the above sentence? Is the sentence structure correct? Should it be rephrased in any other way to make it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence

> This would encourage us to come up with more such content as these.

could be improved

> This would encourage us to come up with more content like this.

Note that "content" is singular, but you use "these". I also rephrased your "more such".

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue with agreement. *Content* is singular, but "these" is plural. There's also a problem with syntax. You can say either of the following:

> More such content.
> More content such as this.

That is, *such* can modify content all by itself, but if you put "as this" at the end, then *such* needs to introduce it, because *such as* is idiomatic.

Note that it would also be more natural to use the future tense "will encourage" in that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The grammar of your suggested sentence is pretty much fine except that you have referred to "content" as if it is plural by using the word "these."  Also the overuse of "such" reveals that you are not a native speaker, even though it probably isn't grammatically wrong. A close rewrite would be

> If you like our content and appreciate our efforts, please press the G+ button and recommend us. This would encourage us to come up with more of this type of content.

Probably better to write the last sentence more directly, though.

> If you like our content and appreciate our efforts, please press the G+ button and recommend us. This encourages us to create more of this type of content.

The use of "encourage" here is just a little odd, though it's perfectly correct.  Usually encouragement is something a little more verbal than clicking a button.  At the moment I'm not thinking of a better verb, though.